# I cannot use the character input in java

Tags: java, input, character

I was trying to create a BMI calculator, and ask the user whether the input is in meters and kilograms or whether the input in inches and pound. This is my code,

```
package uly14th;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BmiCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char Y, y, Q, n, N; 
        
        int heightInMeters, weightInKilograms, BMI; 
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please state whether you are going to use kilograms & meters or, inches & pounds");
        System.out.println("If you want to use the former please press Y or if you want to use the latter please press N");
        Q = input.next().charAt(0);
        if((Q == y) || (Q == Y)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the height in meters and weight in kilograms in the exact order. ");
            heightInMeters = input.nextInt();
            weightInKilograms = input.nextInt();
            
            BMI =  heightInMeters / (weightInKilograms*weightInKilograms);
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

If the user inputs y the program should go to the next section which is to print out the bmi using a formulae. But as soon as i press y i get this error message, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable y might not have been initialized
at uly14th.BmiCalculator.main. I need to know what i can do?

Comment: `if((Q == y) || (Q == Y))` -> `if((Q == 'y') || (Q =='Y'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assuming 'y' and 'Y' as variables. Use quotes to show that they are characters.

`if((Q == 'y') || (Q == 'Y'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char Y, y, Q, n, N; 
        
        int heightInMeters, weightInKilograms, BMI; 
        
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please state whether you are going to use kilograms & meters or, inches & pounds");
        System.out.println("If you want to use the former please press Y or if you want to use the latter please press N");
        Q = input.next().charAt(0);
        if((Q == 'y') || (Q == 'Y')) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the height in meters and weight in kilograms in the exact order. ");
            heightInMeters = input.nextInt();
            weightInKilograms = input.nextInt();
            
            BMI =  heightInMeters / (weightInKilograms*weightInKilograms);
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` and `Y` need to be initialized before it can be used, set `y='y'`, `Y='Y'` then error will disappear.

```
char Y='Y', y='y', Q, n='n', N='N';
```